# AngularJs $swipe not firing end event on mouseup

Tags: angularjs, swipe

**Question:** Should we check at runtime for a touch device (using Modernizr.touch?) and then use the angular swipe service when it is a touch device and use mouse events when it isn't?

**Objective**: I am writing a Slider Directive and I want to move the slider button.
I want to handle *mousedown*, *mousemove*, and *mouseup* events on the desktop and I want similar behavior on a touch screen. I had this working well with mouse events on the desktop but I've modified the code to use angular's **$swipe** service instead. Now the touch screen functionality works well, but the **mouseup** event on the desktop browsers is lost if it occurs outside of the target element.

Here is a jsBin that demonstrates the $swipe utility: 
http://jsbin.com/berome/1/edit?html,js,console,output

On a touch screen device, the demo functions correctly. The *start* event, *move* events, and *end* event fire respectively when dragging the finger across the target element.

On the desktop, the *start* and *move* events fire, but the *end* event will only fire if the *mousedown* is released whilst still within the target div. This is expected behavior because the *mouseup* is bound to the target element. However, if the cursor is taken outside of the div during a *mousemove* event and then the mouse button is released, no *end* event occurs. Moreover the *mousemove* event will continue to fire when the cursor returns within the target!  (Try it on the demo. It gets stuck in the *mousemove* state until another *mousedown*-*mouseup* sequence within the target)

For the desktop implementation, *mousedown* would be bound to the target element, and *mousemove* and *mouseup* would be bound to the *$window* (or some parent element) from within the *mousedown* event. The *mouseup* would then always fire even when the mouse down is released - even if the cursor is outside the target element! The *mousemove* and *mouseup* would be unbound in the *mouseup* event.

There doesn't seem to be much documentation or examples for using $swipe yet. The ngBook has a paragraph or two but no working example. Any suggestions or comments? I'm leaning towards two implementations: one for touch and one for the desktop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, there is very little documentation for ngTouch's $swipe. Just starting digging into this I am having a hard time finding anything. So thank you for your example. 
The only solution to your problem that I can see from my limited understanding is that you treat it like a scroll on a touch device and cancel. These sentences are from the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/service/$swipe#!):

> If the vertical distance is greater, this is a scroll, and we let the
>   browser take over. A cancel event is sent.
>
> cancel is called either on a touchcancel from the browser, or when we
>   begin scrolling as described above.

I haven't tried any of this, but I this thought occurred to me and I thought it might be useful to you and me (as I'm sure I will have to deal with it soon).